# Nuxt: can't use beforeCreate or beforeMount to check data or redirect

Tags: hook, nuxt.js

I want to have the following in my nuxt page:

```
  beforeCreate() {
    if (!this.$store.getters['experiences/current']) {
      this.$router.push('/experiences');
    }
  },
```

Not 100% sure if I should use `beforeCreate` or `beforeMount` but the idea is, if the  `experiences/current` getter is empty, go to the index page.

If I `console.log(this.$store.getters['experiences/current'])` it *is* actually empty, but the redirect doesn't happen and a template rendering error rises because it relies on `this.$store.getters['experiences/current']`.

So how can I make data validation before first component render and redirect if data is not present?

Comment: Maybe you could use a middleware to handle the redirect instead of a hook, it will give you more options and you'll have a direct access to the store and to the router. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a js [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware/) instead ...

*For ts implementation ...*

```
import { Middleware } from '@nuxt/types'

const myMiddleware: Middleware = ({ store, redirect }) => {
  if (!store.state.applicationState && !store.state.yourProperty) {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}

export default myMiddleware
```